# Java JScrollBar getValue Formatting

Tags: java, jscrollbar

When you do:

```
System.out.println(scrollBar.getValue());
```

What is the value formatted in? Is it pixels, percent?

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is actually number of pixels, even if [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollBar.html#getValue%28%29) doesn't precise it.
This is the amount of pixels that were "scrolled".